# jQuery dynamic Datepicker. I can't show the date value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a table that in every row Im showing a datepicker that after selected they have to print in another column the same date plus 60 days. I have acomplished this when the form is loaded but I cant make it work when datepickers fields are edited and have to show the new date field with the new 60 plus days.

Here is what I have:

```
collectionHolder.find('tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input[id$=_fechaQuedan]').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                    onSelect: function(date){
                        // alert('hola'+ this.datepicker('getDate'));
                        alert('ID'+$(this).attr('id'));
                        alert($(this).datepicker('getDate'));

                    }
    });
});
```

The thing here is that when trying in PLUNKER

`alert($(this).datepicker('getDate'));`

This line work like a charm but in my code with all dinamic fields Im not able to get the date showing my a NULL value.

**EDITED**
After adding

```
alert( $(this).val( $(this).datepicker('getDate') ) );
```

Now I getting [object Object]

Now after selecting the field is setting dd/mm/yy without keeping the selected date.

Comment: Read the docs. `onSelectType: Function( String dateText, Object inst )` *Called when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.*

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace:

```
alert($(this).datepicker('getDate'));
```

with:

```
$(this).val( $(this).datepicker('getDate') );
```

it should work!

Comment: Now is giving me "[object Object]" and after selecting the field is setting dd/mm/yy without keep the selected date. Dont know why

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I solved my issue. It took me a while to solve all the cases. This part of the code solves when the document is ready

This code is outside the document ready function. This do the magic of adding more than 30 days to a date.

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
    return this;
};
```

When document.ready() this code finds every date in my code that its id ends with _fechaQuedan and add an onSelect event to every field in rows inside a table

```
$(this).find('input[id$=_fechaQuedan]').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                onSelect: function(date){

                    var fechQueVenAux = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    var d = new Date();

                    d.setDate(fechQueVenAux.getDate());
                    d.setMonth(fechQueVenAux.getMonth());
                    d.setFullYear(fechQueVenAux.getFullYear());
                    d.addDays(60);
                    var curr_date = d.getDate();
                    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

                    var divFechaVencimiento = curr_date + " / " + curr_month + " / " + curr_year;
                                                                      $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('div#fechaVencimiento').html(divFechaVencimiento);

                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
                }
        });
```

In order to show the selected date into an alert I had to use

```
alert(divFechaVencimiento);
```

To show the selected field into the datepicker after selecting a date I had to use

```
$(this).datepicker('setDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
```

This code adds 60 days to a selected date with the jquery ui datepicker in a table with many rows added dynamically

Regards.